# In java, how do I increase the index of two array(list)s of different sizes at the same time?

Tags: java

I have two ArrayLists in java that have different sizes. ArrayLists 'probs' and 'theDoubles' (sizes 4 and 5 respectively). Array 'dprobs' (Double[5]) is just an Array that copies the values of 'theDoubles'.

Only those items that do not have zero-length (see '.size() > 0') are allowed to be added. One of them is zero-length, and gets replaced by a '0.0' double (added to the 'theDoubles' ArrayList).

My problem is that I do not know how to get this desired output:

```
i=1 j=0
i=2 j=1
i=3 j=2
i=4 j=3
    j=4
```

I get this instead:

```
i=1 j=1
i=2 j=2
i=3 j=3
i=4 j=4
```

Here is my code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (probs.get(i).size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("i: " + i);
                System.out.println("j: " + j);

                theDoubles.add(Double.parseDouble(probs.get(i).get(0).getValue()));
                dprobs[j] = theDoubles.get(j);
            } else {
                theDoubles.add(0.0);
            }
            j++;
        }
        return dprobs;
```

I need to display this ('probs' ArrayList contents):

```
0.0
0.0049522
0.0020487
0.0013568
0.0015332
```

and I am only getting this:

```
0.0049522
0.0020487
0.0013568
0.0015332
```

because 'j' starts at '1' (it ignores the first item, which is '0.0' at index 0).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: what is probs its an Arraylist of arraylists of what?

Comment: You should rewrite your question from scratch.  It doesn't make sense as it is.

Comment: For those wondering about my full code, here it is: http://pastebin.com/nmdYBzYW

Comment: RMT: 'j' is initialized at line 80 in my pastebin paste.

Comment: Kal: probs = private List<List<Attribute>> probs; It's an ArrayList of ArrayLists, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but you should also tell us what you are trying to do because I still have no clue.

Comment: @MrStack -- I agree with toto2. You should consider deleting this and re-writing your question. Given an input of an arraylist of arraylist of attributes, what is your expected output? Your code as it stands is hard to comprehend.

Comment: toto2: Merge input double values (probs) with 0.0 double values. The double values are read from an XML file. If one of them does not return a double, I add a 0.0 double to the 'theDoubles' ArrayList, which is a copy of 'probs' (an ArrayList with 4 double values). So finally, if I get results 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 then '1,1,1,1' will be put in 'theDoubles' and for each 0 value (the zero on the left in this case), merge it with the already existing values.

Comment: Kal: My expected output is the double values obtained from the XPath expressions. If one of the expressions yields a zero-length ArrayList, I must replace that node result with a 0. What I expect is: 0,1,1,1,1 where 0 is a node that gave back no result. If the nodeset results in this: 1,0,1,1,0 then I must output it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to see the full picture because nothing shows where you print the second set of outputs and desired outputs. therefore i will try based on the first set that you posted: you need to increase j only when you are at an i which points to an element that is not zero length. therefore, move the j++ to your "if" block too. it becomes like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (probs.get(i).size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("i: " + i);
            System.out.println("j: " + j);

            theDoubles.add(Double.parseDouble(probs.get(i).get(0).getValue()));
            dprobs[j] = theDoubles.get(j);
            j++;
        } else {
            theDoubles.add(0.0);
        }

    }
    return dprobs;
```

Comment: A.J., this looks indeed like a feasible solution. Thank you. Meanwhile I have figured out the problem in the application as a whole: I was looping through i<5 in the code I posted, but elsewhere, I was using the same variable (dprobs), but inside a '<4' loop. This is why the last item never showed up on the GUI even though it was there.

Comment: you are most welcome and i am happy you figured out the problem :)